# vi/vim repeat :bw with one keystroke?

Tags: vim, vi

I am manually processing a very large number of files and so I use `vim *.txt` to open a batch of files and then `:bw` to close a file and move to the next one in the buffer. This works, but I would like to have a way to repeat `:bw` with one keystroke, the same way that you can use `.` to repeat the last command. (If I use `.`, it repeats the command that I had done before `:bw`, which was `dd`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use any ex command in the meantime you can use `@:` to repeat the last ex command.

Anyway, I recommend a quick mapping like:

```
nnoremap <key> :bwipeout<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get this down to two keystrokes by recording a macro: `qa:bw<enter>q`. The macro is then called with `@a` (or `@@` if it was the last macro used). Especially if you are passing over many consecutive files, `@@` is much faster/easier to type than `:bw`.

Comment: why not create a mapping? E.g. `<leader>x` to save and exit current buffer?

Comment: I remapped `Q` to `@@` since I don't use Ex-mode, at least not on a daily basis. Maybe that'll help you